# Emacs evil: space as a prefix key in motion state

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I want to be able to navigate windows with SPC h/j/k/l. I can just put (**wrong, see edit**)

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC h") 'evil-window-left)
```

for normal state (or I could go and use `evil-leader`...), but neither of these work for doing the same thing in motion state. If I put

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC h") 'evil-window-left)
```

then I get the error

```
error: Key sequence SPC h starts with non-prefix key SPC
```

I then tried to undefine `SPC` in motion state

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "SPC" nil)
```

but that doesn't get rid of the error.

How do I do this? I would prefer a solution that only changes the behaviour of SPC in motion state. I suspect the answer lies in `define-prefix-command` but the emacs wiki page is confusing.

EDIT:

That top line of code doesn't work. For some reason I thought it was working in normal mode but I'm getting the same error. So I can go use evil-leader, but that doesn't work in motion state

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track, trying to unset the space key, but `define-key` will read "SPC" as <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, not spacebar.

It must be `(kbd "SPC")` or `" "` (they are equivalent; the former evaluates to the latter):

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map " " nil)
```

Then these should work:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC h") 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC j") 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC k") 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC l") 'evil-window-right)
```

Comment: This was the closest I found to an answer when trying to search why I couldn't get a `use-package`'s `:bind` to interpret a leader key like "space" when binding a sequence: I was using `define-key`'s string representation (just `" "`) but apparently I needed to use `kbd`'s string representation (`"SPC "`).